# Calling python script with parameters from tcl

Tags: python, tcl, exec, zip

I want to execute a python function that have 2 parameters in my TCL program. My python function for dezipping a file.zip is defined by this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import zipfile 
import os.path 
import os 

def dezipFile(filezip, pathdst = ''):

    if pathdst == '': pathdst = os.getcwd() 
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filezip,'r')

    for i in zfile.namelist():
            print (i)
            if os.path.isdir(i): 
                    try: os.makedirs(pathdst + os.sep + i) 
                    except: pass 
            else: 
                    try: os.makedirs(pathdst + os.sep + os.path.dirname(i)) 
                    except: pass 
                    data = zfile.read(i)                  
                    fp = open(pathdst + os.sep + i, "wb") 
                    fp.write(data)                         
                    fp.close() 
    zfile.close()
```

Then, I want to execute this function in my TCL program. I have used `exec`.
TCL script:

```
puts "--outzip is: $outZip"
puts "--destinationDeZip is: $destinationDeZip"
set zip_status [ catch {exec python dezipFile.py ${outZip} ${destinationDeZip}} id ]
if {$zip_status == 1} {
    puts "**** Error: $id *********"
} else {
    puts "**** Pass: the zipped file $fileName is extracted *********"
}
```

In the result report, I have found the message `**** Pass: the zipped file $fileName is extracted *********`.
The command seems to be passed, however the the zipped files are not extracted as expected. Is there any error in my program?

Thks.

Comment: Why use Python for the decompression/ unarchiving task, and not Tcl directly? See my supplemental answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some extra code on the Python side to actually call the function you defined.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    dezipFile(*sys.argv[1:])
```

The `sys.argv[1:]` gets all the arguments after the script name, and doing `dezipFile(*…)` passes all of those into the `dezipFile` function as separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as an answer, more as a suggestion for improvement: I assume you are aware that you do not have resort to Python to decompress and access the content of a ZIP archive in Tcl?

You might want to consider using the `tcllib` module `zipfile::decode`, for a start:

```
package require Tcl 8.6
package require zipfile::decode

try {
    ::zipfile::decode::unzipfile $outZip $destinationDeZip
} on error {errMsg opts} {
    # ...
}
```

(This assumes Tcl 8.6 being available to you.)